# The function with different count of parameters

Tags: erlang

I am just wondering if there is any way to create the same function with different count of parameters?  Something like this:

```
sum_of_n(Num)->
    sum_of_n(Num, 0);
sum_of_n(0, Accum)->
    Accum;
sum_of_n(Num, Accum) ->
    sum_of_n(Num - 1, Accum + Num).
```

As I see Erlang doesn't allow to create the function with one and two parameters the same time. Is there a good way to create such function or I need use two different functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have two different functions with the same name, but different number of arguments:

```
sum_of_n(Num)->
    sum_of_n(Num, 0). %% Note the period

sum_of_n(0, Accum)->
    Accum;
sum_of_n(Num, Accum) ->
    sum_of_n(Num - 1, Accum + Num).
```

In `export`, `fun`, etc. you can refer to them as `FunName/NumberOfArgs`, e.g.

```
-export([sum_of_n/1]).
```

Answer (score 9):

You were almost there!

You only continue function heads with a `;` if there are the same arity (number of arguments). You can happily have functions with the same name but different arity - just use `.` to terminate each arity block:

```
sum_of_n(Num)->
    sum_of_n(Num, 0).

sum_of_n(0, Accum)->
    Accum;
sum_of_n(Num, Accum) ->
    sum_of_n(Num - 1, Accum + Num).
```

Comment: Correct. In Erlang, a function is identified not just by its name, but by its name AND the number of its arguments (arity).

Answer (score 1):

With this tutorial, you will be sure of many things in Erlang.
`learn you some erlang for great good`